# copy large table from sql server to odbc linked database (postgresql) in ssms

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, odbc, ssms

I'm trying to copy created a whole database in SQL Server to Postgres. I've been trying to write a script that can run in ssms with a postgres instance set up as a linked server. This will not be a one off operation.

I've managed to create a script that creates most of the schema i.e. tables, constraints, indexes etc. I do this by using the information_schema tables in sql server and formatting the data to form valid sql for postgres and run `EXEC(@sql) AT POSTGRES` statement, where `POSTGRES` is the linked server and `@SQL` a variable containing my statement. This is working fine.

Now I'm trying to insert the data using a statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(POSTGRES,'SELECT * FROM targettable')
SELECT *
FROM sourcetable
```

The statements are actually slightly modified in some cases to deal with different data types, but this is the idea. The problem is when the table is particularly large, this statement fails with the error :

```
Msg 109, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.
```

I think the error is caused by either postgre or sql server using too much memory generating the large statement. I've found that if I manually select only parts of the data to insert at a time, it works. For instance, the top 10000 rows. But I don't know a way to write a general statement to select only x amount of rows at a time that isn't specific to the table I'm referencing.

Perhaps someone can suggest a better way of doing this though. Keep in mind I do need to change some of the data before inserting it into postgres e.g. geospatial information is transformed to a string so postgres will be able to interpret it.

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to `INSERT INTO` a `SELECT` seems a bit odd. Can you enable `log_statement = 'all'` in the PostgreSQL server, reload it, and then show what appears in the PostgreSQL logs? Edit your question with the log output, comment here when done.

Comment: I know it's a weird notation, have a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) on documentation from microsoft about the openquery function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the `OFFSET X ROWS FETCH NEXT Y ROWS ONLY` introduced in SQL Server 2012 so the complete statement looked like this:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(POSTGRES,'SELECT * FROM targettable')
SELECT *
FROM sourcetable
ORDER BY 1
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY
```

And everything is working and error appears! I actually iterate through the `OFFSET` value adding 10,000 to it on every iteration using dynamic SQL.

Not the cleanest or nicest solution. I think most people would be better writing something in another language as mentioned by Michal Niklas, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have transfered some large databases and for PostgreSQL I see 2 ways:

1. export data into CSV file, convert CSV file into PostgreSQL `COPY` format (see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY) and use `COPY` (wiki page shows more alternatives)
2. make Jython program that connect to both databases (Python is easy and Jython can work with JDBC drivers), make SELECT from source database (if you have a lot od data then use `setFetchSize()`), use PreparedStatement with INSERT in destination database and then `dest_insert_stmt.setObject(i, src_rs.getObject(i))`

Comment: The second point seems potentially a good idea for what I wanted. But I have better knowledge of TSQL so I went that route in the end! However, I will investigate learning about Python and Jython at some point.

Comment: I am now investigating the second suggestion you made as I had some problems with geospatial data and speed using odbc. Are you suggesting I used zxJDBC for connecting to the database or use the jdbc connection directly? If zxJDBC, I can't figure out how to do bulk inserts... Thanks